# Extract table permissions from SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, permissions, extract

How do you extract user roles with type = database role from a table`s permission so I can put this permission in another Create Table script, so the new table has the same user role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this - inspect the system catalog views `sys.database_permissions` and `sys.database_principals`:

```
SELECT
    dp.class,
    dp.class_desc,
    dp.permission_name,
    object_name(dp.major_id) 'Database object',
    p.name 'Granted to',
    dp.major_id,
    object_name(dp.major_id),
    dp.minor_id,
    dp.grantee_principal_id,
    dp.type,
    dp.state,
    dp.state_desc
FROM 
    sys.database_permissions AS dp
INNER JOIN 
    sys.database_principals AS p ON dp.grantee_principal_id = p.principal_id
WHERE
    class = 1   -- object-level permissions
```

Read more about [sys.database_permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188367.aspx) and [sys.database_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx) in the MSDN SQL Server Books Online.

**Update:** if you want to limit it to a single table, use this `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE
    class = 1   -- object-level permissions
    AND dp.major_id = OBJECT_ID('your-table-name-here')
```

Comment: Where in this script do I put my own table? to get the permissions?